# Excel: Formula search for individual word in cells that contain multiple words

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to mark a list as completed where completed tasks say 'Done' next to them (in Column B). In Column C I am writing the progress of each task in and when completed need to write the date that it was completed (ie "Finished 27/02")

Unfortunately if I include a date in the following formula it doesn't recognise the test.

=IF(C1="FINISHED","DONE","")

Is there anything I can add to indicate that the cell doesn't need to contain only the exact text "Finished" but so long is it contains that word it should return the value "Done"

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FINISHED",C1)),"DONE","")
```

Comment: For more information this can be found at [In This Article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/check-if-a-cell-contains-text-HP003056106.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNTIF` with `wildcards`, e.g.

`=IF(COUNTIF(C1,"*FINISHED*"),"DONE","")`

Comment: Thank you... It's actually to form part of a formula but I'm struggling to nest it - would you mind advising me on how to include it in the following: =IF(H63="FINISHED","DONE",IFERROR(IF(E63=DATE,"TODAY",(IF(E63>0,NETWORKDAYS(TODAY(),E63),"Error"))-1),""))   Thanks!

Comment: I assume DATE is a "named range"? TRy this version: `=IF(COUNTIF(H63,"*FINISHED*"),"DONE",IFERROR(IF(E63=DATE,"TODAY",IF(E63>0,NETWORKDAYS(TODA‌​Y(),E63)-1,"Error")),""))`